# How to change each string in a column based on a fuzz.ratio condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column that has the label of some occupation named `data['LIBELLE_EMPLOI_GRADE']`
and a have a list of labels that are written in standard form called labels_T
`labels_T = [lib for code, lib in dict_F_P_T.items()]`. I am trying to see if the string in the column matches one of the strings in labels_T, if that is the case i want to replace it with the string in labels_T.
Here is the code that i tried :

```
for index, value in data['LIBELLE_EMPLOI_GRADE'].iteritems():
    for label in labels_T:
        if fuzz.ratio(value, label) >= 92:
            data.at[index, 'LIBELLE_EMPLOI_GRADE'] = label
```

The problem is when I try this `data.at[index, 'LIBELLE_EMPLOI_GRADE'] = 'Agent de maîtrise principal'` is works for the single line, but when i run the loop the values in the dataframe don't change.
I don't know where is the problem with this code.

Comment: Can you give an example of the input data, e.g. `df = pd.DataFrame(..)`.

Comment: here are the inputs [(index, value) for index, value in nice['LIBELLE_EMPLOI_GRADE'].iteritems()] [(0, 'Adjoint administratif'),
 (1, 'Adjoint administratif'),
 (2, 'Adjoint administratif'),

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `data['LIBELLE_EMPLOI_GRADE']` has unique values. Otherwise, you need to produce the dictionary of transformations first to minimize the process time.
What you can do is merge them together and then get the results you want:

```
from itertools import product

MATCH_SCORE = 92
permutations = pd.DataFrame(
    list(product(data['LIBELLE_EMPLOI_GRADE'].to_list(), labels_T)), 
    columns=['LIBELLE_EMPLOI_GRADE', 'label']
)
permutations["score"] = permutations.apply(
    lambda row: fuzz.ratio(row["LIBELLE_EMPLOI_GRADE"],row["label"])
)
permutations = permutations[permutations["score"] > MATCH_SCORE ]
```

The resulted data frame contains all matches with matching score higher than 92%.

Just be careful since some `"LIBELLE_EMPLOI_GRADE"` might have multiple matches.